# Pickled Punk Question

Tags: pathfinder-2e, undead

I was wondering if a [pickled punk](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=2481) can activate the automatic damage from the second part of their attach ability, even with no remaining actions. The full ability reads:

> Attach When a pickled punk hits a target larger than itself, it uses bizarre excretions to adhere to that creature. This is similar to Grabbing the creature, but the pickled punk is not flat-footed, and it moves with that creature rather than holding it in place.
>
> **Each turn while attached, the pickled punk automatically deals the damage from its jaws Strike to the creature to which it's attached. It also wriggles about, gaining a +2 circumstance bonus to AC as long as it's not also grabbed or restrained**.

So if I summon pickled punk with animate dead, and I already use its two actions (as per minion logic) to say move and then attack, the attack hits and activates attach, can I use the second part of attaches damage to make a free jaws strike?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The Punk Automatically Deals Damage

> Each turn while attached, the pickled punk automatically deals the damage from its jaws Strike to the creature to which it's attached.

They don't need to make a Strike using their jaws to deal this damage, it happens automatically each turn while attached. So even if a summoned pickled punk wasn't given a command they would still deal this damage automatically each turn, though it wouldn't be a "free jaws Strike".

### When do they Deal Damage?

The Attach ability doesn't mention any timing for when this automatic damage applies, and doesn't qualify for any of the standard timings described in the rules for [Turns](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=435) like round limited or sustained actions. Without some action(s) or free action required from the punk this damage would occur at either the beginning or end of their turn.

Dealing damage at the end of the punk's turn as you've mentioned would effectively double their damage to 2d6+6 for a single successful Strike, which is well beyond the [extreme Strike damage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1018) for a higher level 2 creature and likely not the intended result. Avoiding that by having the damage occur at the start of the punk's turn is probably best, and most in-line with the narrative of them continually gnawing on the target.